# Python Unicode Conversion for character 'ñ'

Tags: python

I have to print Unicode of char 'ñ'
E.g. Input - 'Piñeiro'
Output - 'Pi\xf1eiro' (Codecs Used - raw_unicode_escape)
**Expected - 'Pi\u00f1eiro'**

I tried other standard encoding and text encoding codecs from  https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings but seems non of this from the table is producing the required output

Any suggestions on which encoding module is required to get required output?

Comment: I see you already asked [another question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/69402000/python-unicode-conversion-for-latin-characters) about this conversion, but it did not fully solve your problem. This very much seems like an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. If you can update your question with more details about what you're trying to achieve, we can give you the prober answer. (1/2)

Comment: By asking these type of questions you probably will get new problems after each answer. For example, in your next step you might want to decode data from the API. Did you already consider that? The answer below provides a way that seems to solve your **encoding** problem, but there would be no way to reliably **decode** that data. You also mentioned something about a 'b' character that is used for other purposes... So it seems we do not have all the information to give you the right answer. (2/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to print out `Pi\u00f1eiro` -- a string of length 11 --  and not `Piñeiro` -- a string of length 7, you could do

```
In [93]: mytext = "Pi\u00f1eiro"

In [94]: print(mytext)
Piñeiro

In [95]: new_text = "".join(["\\u{:04x}".format(ord(c)) if ord(c) > 0x7f else c for c in mytext])

In [96]: print(new_text)
Pi\u00f1eiro

In [97]: new_text
Out[97]: 'Pi\\u00f1eiro'
```

How you determine which characters to show like this is up to you. I somewhat arbitrarly picked any characters whose [unicode code unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) is greater than [007F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character).